# Git error. Command: with exit code 128 in Flutter

Tags: git, flutter, pubspec

attempting to use this package in my flutter application

```
plain_notification_token:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:zionnite/plain_notification_token.git
```

[image]

Have deleted `/.pub-cache` yet error still persists

**please what do I need to Do?**

Answer (score 1):

so I decided to use the full url from GitHub like this

```
  plain_notification_token:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zionnite/plain_notification_token.git
```

I was then able to run the `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Just ran into this problem as well, any idea why this wasn't working with the original url?

Comment: my best guess is that it was not well imported to flutter pub.dev